# Unable to add floors in Mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to add 2 or 3 floors for each building using MapBox GL, but when i try using the addlayer, the colours are getting overriden but no layers or floors are added. Been stuck with this for some time now.

I want 3d extrusions of floors in a building.

Tried putting this into a button click as well, but still it is not returning expected results.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div id='map'>
</div>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGFuc3dpY2siLCJhIjoiY2l1dTUzcmgxMDJ0djJ0b2VhY2sxNXBiMyJ9.25Qs4HNEkHubd4_Awbd8Og';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-87.61694, 41.86625],
    zoom: 15.99,
    pitch: 40,
    bearing: 20
});

map.on('load', function() {

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'room-extrusion10',
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'source': 'composite',
        'source-layer': 'building',
        'paint': {
            'fill-extrusion-color': 'blue',
            'fill-extrusion-height': {
                'type': 'identity',
                'property': 'height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-base': {
                'type': 'identity',
                'property': 'max_height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-opacity': 1
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'room-extrusion11',
        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
        'source': 'composite',
        'source-layer': 'building',
        'paint': {
            'fill-extrusion-color': 'red',
            'fill-extrusion-height': {
                'type': 'identity',
                'property': 'height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-base': {
                'type': 'identity',
                'property': 'min_height'
            },
            'fill-extrusion-opacity': 1
        }
    },'room-extrusion10');

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fill-extrusion-height`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-fill-extrusion-height) and [`fill-extrusion-base`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#paint-fill-extrusion-base) are the paint properties that control the lower and upper height (in meters) of a fill-extrusion feature. In your example these are styled with [identity functions](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#function-type) based on building height data from OpenStreetMap (in the Mapbox Streets data source), causing them to imitate real-world building shapes (as best as they are mapped). In order to create a fill-extrusion layer that spans only one floor you'd want `fill-extrusion-height: 3` (or however tall, in meters, you perceive one story to be) and `fill-extrusion-base: 0` for the first floor; the second would be height=6 and base=3, and so forth.

Note that in all released versions of Mapbox GL JS, multiple fill-extrusion layers [don't render correctly](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4134) with respect to each other. This is [fixed](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/5101) in master and will be included in the next release this month.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Can you also let me know on how to restrict the extrusions to be displayed for a single building or property rather than the entire city in the map. I want to concentrate on a single building and add respective layers or floors based on the fill-extrusion-height and fill-extrusion-base properties.